# Importing a directory of modules in ESM

Tags: javascript

I have a directory of folders, each folder has an index.js I'd like to import.

```
modules/
├── moduleA/
│   └── index.js
└── moduleB/
    └── index.js
```

How would I tackle this in ESM?

Is this something that is only achieveable with fs? in CommonJS you can do something like:

```
require('./modules/**/index.js', {mode: (base, files) => {
   console.log(files)
}});
```

Comment: Are you talking Node.js, or browser? `import` does not have such a syntax available.

Comment: browser, that's unfortunate then

Comment: You will have to `import` each module separately. If you have an array of importable paths leading to your modules, you can do it in a loop, but that array is nothing that vanilla JS can give you out of the box.

Comment: Also since Javascript cannot access your file system, I assume there is no way to make something similar work *at runtime*. *build time*  is a different thing, it then depends on your bundling tool.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using webpack. I'll try out that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to import each module separately. If you have an array of importable paths leading to your modules, you can do it in a loop, but that array is nothing that vanilla JS can give you out of the box.

If you're using webpack to bundle your JS assets, you could give [webpack-import-glob](https://github.com/brunoosilva/webpack-import-glob) a shot.